# Android not capturing camera content view - black screen only - Android 10

Tags: java, android

So the app I have, takes a photograph (or uses from library) and brings the captured photo into an editing view. The code for the camera capture is;

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

The camera view opens, allows me to take a photo, but when it moves to `EditorActivity.class` the photo is not there, just a black screen. The editor view is fine, but it does not seem to be taking what I capture with the camera. I have set the correct permissions, this works fine in versions prior to Level 23
SDK version.

Edit - updated code methods below;

boolean SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
File file = new File(myDir, fname);
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });

return false;
```

}

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 2:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "work here");
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    SaveImage(thumbnail);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: We cannot see how you save that bitmap nor how you would use the saved file in a different activity.  What do you expect ftom us?

Comment: I have added the save code now to original post

Comment: `void SaveImage(Bitmap....` Make that `boolean SaveImage(Bitmap..`. Return false if there is an exception. Let the caller check the return value.

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Do not blindly call mkdirs. Call it only if the directory does not exist yet. Let the function return false if mkdirs fails.

Comment: If you try to delete a file then check the return value and handle accordingly if it fails.

Comment: Thank you, have added updated code, still same issue :/ - I should say I am quite new to Android so if I sound silly, I apologise in advance.

Comment: You have done nothing with mkdirs and exceptions. Nor is the caller checking a return value. Please do all the things we ask otherwise this takes ages.

Comment: `return false;` At the end of the function you should return true.

Comment: I am testing on 2 phones, Pixel 3 & Nexus 6, neither have SD Card option, could this be the issue? That it is trying a directory that doesn't exist?

Comment: Please do the things i mentioned in my comments.